# Easiest way to update a OleDB table from a DataTable

Tags: vb.net, datatable, oledb

What's the easiest way (`vb.NET`) to update a full `OleDB` table from a previous modified imported table?

Here's what I have.

First I import the table from an `Access` Database:

```
Dim PRDB As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;                                    
                      Data Source=<location>;
                      Jet OLEDB:Database Password=<password>"                                                        
Dim CNDB As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(PRDB)                                                                              
Dim CMDB As New OleDb.OleDbCommand                                                                                
Dim ADDB As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(CMDB)                                                                       
Dim TBDB As New DataTable                                                                                                    

Try : CNDB.Open()
Catch EX As Exception : MsgBox(EX.ToString) : End Try

Try : CMDB.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [TABLE 01]" : ADDB.Fill(TBDB)
Catch EX As Exception : MsgBox(EX.ToString) : End Try
```

So far so good. I managed to import `TABLE 01` successfully to `TBDB`.

Now, let's say I change one cell of the `DataTable`:

```
TBDB.Rows(2).Item(3) = "CHANGED"
```

Is there a way to update directly the `OleBD` table without describing the changed cell adress? Something like

```
ADDB.Update(TBDB) (?)
```

I already tried the last bit of code but it didn't work (I think it works only if the argument is a `DataRow` not a `DataTable`).

I researched this matter, but all the answers I found looked a lit bit complicated for this (apparent) simple task. So I wonder if there is a more direct way to do this - I also read something about `Binders`, but I didn't quite understand the method.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe [OleDbCommandBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbcommandbuilder?view=netframework-4.8) can help.

Comment: @Fadi, yes! It did help! Thanks a lot...

Comment: @Fadi, will you formalize your comment on an answer? I will accept it and vote it up if you do.

Comment: I think it will be better for other if you post your working code as answer and accept it, because I never work with OleDb, I just face similar problem with Sqlite, also my English is very bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Fadi, I managed to get the exact method I was looking for using the `OleDbCommandBuilder`:

```
Dim CMNDBUID As OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder
CMNDBUID = New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(ADDB)
CMNDBUID.GetUpdateCommand()
```

Then I can easily update the `Access` table:

```
Try : ADDB.Update(TBDB)
Catch EX As Exception : MsgBox(EX.ToString) : End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL SERVER the equivalent is:

```
Private Sub UpdateDBFromDataTable(myDataTable As DataTable)
    'Change with your connection string
    Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source = MyServerName/Instance; Integrated Security=true; Initial Catalog=YourDatabase"

    Using connection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        connection.Open()

        Using bulkCopy As SqlBulkCopy = New SqlBulkCopy(connection)

            For Each c As DataColumn In myDataTable.Columns
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(c.ColumnName, c.ColumnName)
            Next

            'Put here your table name in Database
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = myDataTable.TableName

            Try
                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(myDataTable)
            Catch ex As Exception
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is nothing what I asked for. I'm not even working with SQL here.

Comment: Even in Sql Server this would be a bit of overkill for a single record change.